# Passing Auth User from PHP / Laravel to JavaScript

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, security, authentication

The following approach has been suggested in a few SO answers as a way of passing authenticated user details from backend (PHP/Laravel) to frontend (JavaScript/Vue). However, I would like to confirm how secure it is.

```
<script>
    window.App = {!! json_encode([
        'user' => Auth::user()
    ]); !!};
</script>
```

Are there any security implications of passing authenticated user details to JavaScript using this approach assuming details do contain user-generated input like name and username? Can JavaScript code safely handle this data to authorize user actions and/or output any of this data as HTML?

Or is there anything that a user can type into Name/Username fields during registration that can break this code / pose a security concern? Is there any benefit in sanitizing output of `json_encode()` before passing it to JavaScript?

**EDIT**

As an example, let's say I get this data from the server, pass it to JavaScript using `json_encode()` and then output user name in HTML using JavaScript. Can this be exploited in any way if users are allowed to enter anything (up to a certain char limit) into the Name field during registration?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Can JavaScript code safely handle this data to authorize user actions" - never, because it's client-side and by definition not under your control. Authorization is done server-side.

"Or is there anything that a user can type into Name/Username fields during registration that can break this code / pose a security concern?" - `json_encode` escapes characters so that whatever data you have the outputed JSON is valid.

"output any of this data as HTML?" - no. You need to sanitize the data *for* HTML output. `json_encode` does not know what HTML is.

"Is there any benefit in sanitizing output of json_encode() before passing it to JavaScript?" - this is not something decided at a language level but at an application level. If users are allowed to input *any* characters then you are responsible to ensure that they can't exploit that in nefarious ways because only you know how that data is used by the application.

"However, I would like to confirm how secure it is." - it's as secure as you understand the implications of passing around data between different contexts. In this situation you are passing data that's "secure" in the server-side context but unchecked might not be "secure" when passed to the client-side context.

TLDR: no one can give you a satisfying answer without knowing what you're doing with that data. Simply inserting it in the response as a `<script>` would be safe. Using said data client-side might not be safe depending on what you do with it.

Here's an example of why *not* sanitizing data is bad: https://jsfiddle.net/v7pxn48j/
As you can see there is nothing wrong with the JSON, but interpreting some of it as unsanitized HTML is.

Comment: Brilliant. Exactly what I wanted to confirm.